# How to automatically create an object for a model in Django, if it doesn't exist?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models. One is for UserProfile and the other is for Company.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'company')

class Company(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I am using Django Rest Framework for user creation. What I want to achieve is when I create a new user, I want to assign a company_name to that user. And if that company_name is not present in the db, then I want to create it on the go. But it is throwing an error. **"Invalid hyperlink - No URL match."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `@property` to tackle this problem in a clean and simple way. It works well for creating and for updating the object aswell. Note that the **UserPorifle**'s field is renamed to **company**. Here is how you do it:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company')

    @property
    def company_name(self):
         return self.company.name

    @company_name.setter
    def company_name(self, value):
        self.company, _ = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=value)
```

Now you can create objects using:

```
UserProfile.objects.create(company_name='Some name')
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to link your UserProfile Model with the user. It should be a OnetoOne Relationship because a User should only have one company I guess.

In your serializer you should add in the Company model and save the company name from the input in the API and then connect it to the new user that is being created.